# getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, classloader

Пожалуйста, объясните мне, что делает эта конструкция?

```
InputStream is = Solution.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(args[1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возвращает поток ввода из ресурса, имя которого содержится в аргументе командной строки.

Answer (score 0):

А если точнее возращяет поток из ресурса название которого хранится во втором аргументе командной строки запуска приложения